# Is there a way to write a recursive function that multiplies the even numbers from 1 to n using c?

Tags: c, recursion

I've found similar questions that do that to the sums of even numbers, but when i try to change that to the product of these, it always ends up printing out 0.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int SumEven(int num1, int num2)
{
   if(num1>num2)
    return 0;
return num1*SumEven(num1+2,num2);
}
int main()
{
    int num1=2,num2;
    printf("Enter your Limit:");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    printf("Sum of all even numbers in the given range is: %d",SumEven(num1,num2));
}
```

this is an example of one of those i tried to adapt but it only returns 0, any ideas?

Comment: You should include your current (non-working) code for inspection; otherwise the answer to your question will just be “yes, there is a way”, which you won’t find too helpful.

Comment: If you have a stray zero term in a summing problem, the value does not change; but if you reuse the code structure for a product problem, that zero is a kiss of death.  Add debug printing to all the elementary operations: like this was multiplied by that, resulting in that.  Use a debugger; catch it where it has the zero.

Comment: oh ok, but i dont have anything yet tho

Comment: If you want to multiply then use the neutral element of the multiplication, ie 1 in place of 0 (neutral element for addition)

Answer (score 0):

You need to post code for a question like this.  But the probable cause-  when you do a sum, you start with an initial value of 0.  When you do products, it needs to be 1.  Otherwise you multiply 0*i, which is always 0.

Comment: thanks, but i thought num1 at the post above started at 2, right? whats multiplying what by 0?

Comment: When you sum things, you start with an initial value.  That's going to be 0.  When you take the produce of things, you also need an initial value, but it needs to be 1.  This isn't the values you're taking the product of, its the initial value of the result.

Comment: @Guilhermando Ok, you have a really odd implementation of sum.  In this case its not the initial value that has to be 1, it's the return value in the terminal case-  return 1 instead of return 0.

Comment: ok so which values should i be editing there?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of thought, I am revising my original answer even though it is a workable solution.  Actually, all that you would need to do is change one line of code.  Instead of the following linesof code.

```
if(num1>num2)
   return 0;
```

You just need to do the following.

```
if(num1>num2)
    return 1;
```

Following were some small limit test results that agreed with manual calculations.

```
:~/C_Programs/Console/MultEven/bin/Release$ ./MultEven 
Enter your Limit:4
Sum of all even numbers in the given range is: 8
:~/C_Programs/Console/MultEven/bin/Release$ ./MultEven 
Enter your Limit:8
Sum of all even numbers in the given range is: 384
:~/C_Programs/Console/MultEven/bin/Release$ ./MultEven 
Enter your Limit:10
Sum of all even numbers in the given range is: 3840
```

Try that out.

Regards.